# How to access the data from an array of objects by TextInput in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects in console. I want to get the id of the name that is entered in the TextInput by user. here is the result of:
`console.log("All teams", Teams);`
`console.log("Selected team: ", myTeam);`

```
All teams: 
Array [
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "616e33b163d7ed23e95a9d98",
    "name": "test_team",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6181c5b3b5dfd98d4206e915",
    "name": "Team2",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6181c5d9b5dfd98d4206e919",
    "name": "team3",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6181c5e0b5dfd98d4206e91c",
    "name": "team4",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6181c5e4b5dfd98d4206e91f",
    "name": "team5",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6181c681b5dfd98d4206e924",
    "name": "team6",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "618a046dbdb0ee4648b9da0f",
    "name": "sprinters",
  },
  
Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "618a058ebdb0ee4648b9da15",
    "name": "phone stepper",
  },
]
```

Selected team: Team2

the value of Team2 is from user's entry, I need to get the value of this entry's "_id", something like " The id for this entry is: 6181c5b3b5dfd98d4206e915"
How should I solve this problem? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can use `filter` here.

Comment: sorry, the description is not really what you're trying to archive. Can you provide expected output data?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the find method on your array to pick out the first object with the name 'Team2', then access the `_id` property.

```
const id = allTeamsArr.find(obj => obj.name === 'Team2')['_id']
```

Comment: Thank you so much I changed it as bellow, and returned what I need!
  const id = teams.find((obj: {name:any;}) => obj.name == myteam) ['_id']

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.filter function to filter out.

```
var arr =[
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "616e33b163d7ed23e95a9d98", "name": "test_team" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "6181c5b3b5dfd98d4206e915", "name": "Team2" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "6181c5d9b5dfd98d4206e919", "name": "team3" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "6181c5e0b5dfd98d4206e91c", "name": "team4" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "6181c5e4b5dfd98d4206e91f", "name": "team5" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "6181c681b5dfd98d4206e924", "name": "team6" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "618a046dbdb0ee4648b9da0f", "name": "sprinters" },
    
     { "__v": 0, "_id": "618a058ebdb0ee4648b9da15", "name": "phone stepper" } ]
    
    var input = '6181c5b3b5dfd98d4206e915';
    var selected = arr.filter((item) => item._id == input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it by calling the below function on change event of Textinput:

```
     <TextInput  onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
          
      onChangeHandler = (e)=> {
        const teamId = allTeams.filter(obj => obj.name === e.target.value)['_id']
        console.log(e.target.value, teamId)
       }
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, as filter would return an array, even if it only had one result. It would need to be this in that case.. `const teamId = allTeams.filter(obj => obj.name === e.target.value)[0]['_id']`

Comment: Yes, you are right, we could access it using array index